# Image of a Borel set is a borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$, if $E$ is a family of subsets of $A$ and $E$ is a $B-algebra$ (borel algebra). My question is:

Is $f(E) = \{\ f(V) | V \in E \}$ a  $B-algebra$. I suppose that this is false but how can I construct a counterexample to show it?

If someone could help me please. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: (1) Did you mean $E$ is the family of Borel sets of $A$? (2) No hypothesis on $f$?

Comment: yea is f(E) and no hypothesis of f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $B = A$, the discrete topology in the left, the indiscrete topology in the right, $f =$ identity.